# How to set constantly incrementing counter in javascript , to perform another operation when counter > certain value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jquery and javascript . I need to set up a variable in javascript which is incrementing by 1 after each second . For that I did following :

```
    function run(){         
      timer++;  
    }// run ends here

   setInterval(run,1000);
```

Once the variable value is > 5, I want to enable code such that, whenever somebody hovers over iframe in html page, ajax request is done .

After sinigle ajax request I want to reset timer= 0.

```
if(timer>5){
$("iframe").hover(function(){

        $.ajax({
          url:     'http://localhost/test.html',
          cache:   false,
          data:    'html',
          success: function(data,status) {
          }
        });          
});

  timer=0;
}
```

This process should repeat again, counter should again start from 0 to 5 and ajax request functionality should be activated again .

Below is the complete code in one place :

```
<script>

var i = 0;
var timer=0;

        function run(){         
            timer++;    
        }// run ends here

        setInterval(run,1000);          

        if(timer>5){
        $("iframe").hover(function(){

                $.ajax({
                  url:     'http://localhost/test.html',
                  cache:   false,
                  data:    'html',
                  success: function(data,status) {
                  }
                });          
        });

          timer=0;
        }

</script>
```

I tried a lot and googled a lot, but was not able to figure out the solution .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :

```
var timer=0;

function run(){         
    timer++;    

    if(timer == 5){
        $("iframe").on('mouseenter', function(){

            $.ajax({
                url:     'http://localhost/test.html',
                cache:   false,
                data:    'html',
                success: function(data,status) {
                    timer=0;
                    $('iframe').off('mouseenter')
                }
            });          
        });

    }
}// run ends here

setInterval(run,1000);
```

If you already have mouseenter event on you iframe, doing `.off('mouseenter')` will delete those binding.

As Ian suggested, you can name you event allowing you to unbind specifique binding.

To do it, just use a dot when bind/unbinding:

```
$("iframe").on('mouseenter.timer',...)
$('iframe').off('mouseenter.timer')
```

Comment: I missed that. Perhaps you should remove it in your answer, it is a bit confusing... Good answer though!

Comment: Something you might want to suggest is namespacing the `mouseenter` event, so that you don't unbind **all** `mouseenter` events when you use `.off("mouseenter")`. So for example, you'd use `.on("mouseenter.timer", func...)` and `.off("mouseenter.timer")`.

Comment: @Ian, true, that's a good addition in case of conflicts, thank!

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I thought your answer was great before, I just thought this could help, and would localize it so it wouldn't conflict :)

Answer (score 2):

Use function [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) to avoid global "timer" variables:

```
function run(){
  run.timer = run.timer || 0;   
  return run.timer++;
} // run ends here

setInterval(run,1000);
```

And to act accordingly to the timer, run your handling from `run()`, for example:

```
function run(){
    run.timer = run.timer || 0;   
    run.timer = handleTimer(run.timer++);
} // run ends here

setInterval(run,1000);

function handleTimer(timer) {
    if(timer > 5){
        $("iframe").hover(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:     'http://localhost/test.html',
                cache:   false,
                data:    'html',
                success: function(data,status) {
                }
            }); 
            // And disable hover handler once executed
            $("iframe").unbind("mouseenter mouseleave");
        });
        return 0;
    }

    return timer; // continue timer chaining
}
```

Comment: Should we not turn the hovering off too?

Comment: Added the missing return statements in both run() and the handleTimer() functions, otherwise +1

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS, thanks. The value returned from `handleTimer` should still be assigned, though, as it's sometimes reset to 0.

Comment: @mishik You must return it for it to continue incrementing. Notice your console here, it remains at 0 http://jsfiddle.net/q4gDv/

Comment: Yes, I need to return it, that's correct. What I meant is that once returned this value should be assigned to `run.timer`, otherwise it will just continue increasing.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `if` statement in `run()` and move `timer=0` to the `success` function of your AJAX call.

```
function run() {
    timer ++;
    if(timer == 5) {
        //Your ajax here
    }
}
```

Your AJAX `success` should look like `success: function(data, status) { timer = 0;}` In your AJAX success, you will want to `unbind` your `iframe` hover, and then rebind it when `timer > 5` so that the hover functionality is removed when the timer is less than 5.

Comment: if the ajax request is not completed within the second, the run function will keep stacking ajax requests, as the timer is never actually stopped. I think you'ld better use `timer == 5`